# Uniform convergence of series depending on parameter

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Question. Consider $F(\epsilon,M)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{M-2k}\min(\epsilon,2^{k-M})$. Does $F(M,\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in $M$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

In a more abstract setting, let $a_k = a_k(\epsilon,M)$ be a sequence ($0<\epsilon<1$ and $M>0$ are parameters) such that

- $0< a_k < 1$ for all $k$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k < 1$
- $a_k(\epsilon,M) \rightarrow 0$ for fixed $M$ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Question. Can we get, using these asumptions, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k(\epsilon,M) \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in $M$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured this is equivalent to $\min(1,2^M \epsilon)$ which does not uniformly converge (as $\sup\limits_M \min(1,2^M \epsilon) = 1$ does not coverge to $0$).